# Math function to get output desired

Tags: java, math

I am currently learning the basic math functions and I am struggling to get this output for my homework. I think the wording is just making me more and more confused. Thanks in advance for your help! Here is the problem layout:

Z = 7

Use the Math methods and the System.out.println statement to display:

- the square root of z squared plus 1
- Output desired: 7.0710678118654755
- My output: 8

My code:
public class tester {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     int z = 7;
     System.out.println(Math.pow(Math.sqrt(z), 2) + 1);
    
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“the square root of z squared plus 1” means √(*z*<sup>2</sup>+1).

You are currently calculating (√*z*)<sup>2</sup>+1 — which incidentally is the same as *z*+1. Hence why you’re getting 8.

Comment: Thank you! Got jumbled up on the wording I guess. Thank you!

Comment: Well, the z=7 was the clue here, otherwise the statement *the square root of z squared plus 1* can mean at least 3 different variants of expression. It depends where you put the comma in the statement. :)

Answer (score 1):

In this case for a small integral power I would avoid using the `Math.pow` method and do it like this.

```
int z = 7;
System.out.println(Math.sqrt((z*z) + 1));
```

Prints

```
7.0710678118654755
```

Also note that quite often, `int` math doesn't give the correct floating point answer because the conversion to double is done too late. Here the `Math.sqrt` converts the value to a double for you so there is no problem.  But in some cases you would have wanted to specify 1 as 1.0 to force the conversion.

Also note that due to operator precedence, `(z*z)` could have just been `z*z`. But when in doubt or to clarify the meaning, use parens.

Answer (score 0):

"the square root of z squared plus 1" means the square root of 50 if z is 7, because 7*7 = 49 and 49+1 = 50. Try `Math.sqrt(Math.pow(z,2)+1);`